# Physical interpretation of the normal to a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ if the tangent is interpreted as velocity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, intuition

Assume I have a curve $\vec{r}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^3$.  Its tangent vector, $\vec{T} = \vec{\dot{r(t)}}$ can be interpreted as the velocity of a particle moving along the curve (as long as my parameterization is chosen correctly).  The normal vector, though, doesn't seem to have as nice an interpretation.  What is the physical interpretation, assuming there is one, of the normal vector (and the binormal)?

**Edit**: As has been pointed out in comments, the normal vector is not unique.  I shall define "the" normal as:  $\vec{N} = \frac{d\hat{T}}{dt}$, where $\hat{T} = \frac{\vec{T}}{||\vec{T}||}$, and the binormal as $\vec{B} = \vec{T}\times\vec{N}$.  I am specifically interested in the interpretation of $\vec{N}$, unless $\vec{B}$ has a more obvious interpretation.

Comment: Note that normal vector is not unique in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @JJR: agreed.  I've edited the question

Comment: It's not quite what you want, but if $\vec{T}$ is the velocity then $d\vec{T}/dt$ would be the acceleration of the particle.

Comment: @achillehui Only if you assume a circular orbit, I think. (A generic elliptic orbit would have $d\vec{T}/dt$ pointing towards the Sun but not $d\hat{T}/dt$ since $\Vert T\Vert$ isn't constant.)

Comment: @Semiclassical you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal vector can be thought of as **direction of curvature** or, wordily, direction of change of direction. To justify this, let's write the velocity vector as magnitude times direction: $T = v\hat{T}$. Acceleration is the derivative of $T$ with respect to time, so let's apply the product rule:
$$ \frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dt}\hat{T} + v\frac{d\hat{T}}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dt}\hat{T} + vN $$
Acceleration breaks into two components. The first term corresponds to speeding up in the same direction you were going. The second term corresponds to changing direction. So we can interpret $N$ as pointing in the direction about which the curve is, well, curving.

Comment: But in physics the acceleration is the whole of $dT/dt$, only in the uniform motion normal and acceleration are parallel

Comment: @enzotib Yes, that's true, maybe my answer is a misnomer ...

Comment: More simply: $\hat{N}$ points towards the center of curvature at that point on the curve.

Answer (score 1):

It is more obvious to define the binormal unit vector as the unit vector orthogonal to the plane in which the velocity $\mathbf{v}$ and the acceleration $\mathbf{a}$ lay, i.e.:
$$
\mathbf{b}=\frac{\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{a}}{|\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{a}|}
$$
The principal normal unit vector is, by consequence, the unit vector of the unique direction orthogonal to $\mathbf{t}$ and $\mathbf{b}$.